# how come has firebird-superserver stopped and how to prevent from happening again?

Tags: centos

On a CentOS 6.2 x86_64 server I have an instance of Firebird 2.5 that suddenly stopped working. The last part of the /var/log/firebird/firebird.log is:

```
cpc-5556l (Server)      Fri Nov 30 10:12:03 2012
    Error in isc_attach_database() API call when working with security database
    Can't access lock files' directory /tmp/firebird


cpc-5556l (Server)      Fri Nov 30 10:12:35 2012
    INET/inet_error: bind errno = 98


cpc-5556l (Client)      Fri Nov 30 10:12:35 2012
    /usr/sbin/fbguard: /usr/sbin/fbserver terminated due to startup error (2)



cpc-5556l (Client)      Fri Nov 30 10:12:35 2012
    /usr/sbin/fbguard: /usr/sbin/fbserver terminated due to startup error (2)
```

This is a production server, so rebooting it is the very last option. Restarting the service does no good either.

I have googled a bit for these errors and still no luck.

What should I do to solve this?

Thanks in advance,
gtludwig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's plain and clear in the log …

```
Can't access lock files' directory /tmp/firebird
```

Your problem description does not indicate that you did indeed check the basic things, such as permissions on the directory sufficient for the user and groups the Firebird server is running under. So do make those checks. Who knows, the directory might even have been deleted by some ill advised clean-up script.

A reboot should most definitely not be necessary.

Comment: Actually I found out the disc to have some problems, when I rebooted the server, it wouldn't start up back again. Now, I have to un-mount the RAID volume and run fsck for each partition... FUN!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Good luck. By the way, I've found the [Firebird Support List](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/firebird-support/) to be very helpful. Just in case the need should arise for recovery or whatnot. -- M. Ludwig :)

Comment: Thanks, @Lumi, it was easier than expected. I booted with a LiveCD and ran the fsck command to the volume SMART said problematic. After that, I rebooted the server to full funcionality, with Firebird operating as should.

Comment: Glad to hear. And just cool how I was so wrong about a reboot *most definitely* not being necessary … :)